# Does Resharper has a quick code preview like in Roslynator?

Tags: resharper, roslynator

I mean something like this.

[image]

I don't know what it called. Today, I tried a trial version of Resharper and I found Resharper need to click Preview Code to show code changes. I wonder if Resharper has a feature like this.